# Retrieve saved image location taken by camera

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to capture image using my phone camera, but failing to get the image location.

How can I retrieve the Uri?

```
Uri tempUri = null;
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyLibraryManager");
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
tempUri = Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);
cameraIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
cameraIntent.putExtra("outputX", cropwidth);
cameraIntent.putExtra("outputY", cropheight);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_IMAGE_CAPURE);
```

**onActiviryResult:**

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && intent != null){
    Log.d("abd", "Intent: "+ intent);
    Log.d("abd", "location: "+ MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
}
```

**Output**

> abd﹕ Intent: Intent {act=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyLibraryManager/IMG_20160207_135753.jpg (has extras) }
>
> abd﹕ xyz: output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your log:

> Intent
>   {act=file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyLibraryManager/IMG_20160207_135753.jpg
>   (has extras) }

It's in the intent's action. You can get it like:

```
String filePath = intent.getAction();
```

Comment: @abdfahim, I know, it's been fooling me more than once, we should open a bugreport to google, I'm sure it would save hundreds of hours every year :)